# Algorithm that synchronizes two database sources?

Tags: ios, algorithm, sqlite, postgresql, synchronization

I have a iOS SQLite db that is a mirror of a Postgres 9.3 DB (master). It is for an invoicing app.

This app will have several SQLite DBs that are updating and eventually will sync with the master DB (sometimes after several hours). The main activity is make invoices, in which there is an Invoice Header - Invoice Line(s) - Payment(s) relation. The most recent data is the one preferred, and I'm not concerned about conflict resolution (because each device generates its own set of invoices, and it is very rare for two different clients to edit the same record at the same time).

I have it almost working, but the edge cases are making this difficult to test. Also, I suspect this problem has been solved already. Also, I wish to build a test suite that lets me test hundreds of clients talking to dozen of masters, and doing things ad-hoc is not a good idea.

This is what I have now:

https://gist.github.com/mamcx/8958295

My code does this:

1. Create GUIDs and a Version field (autoinc, int) that record the last version for the table. Each change increases the version. Deletes are all logical. This is in both DBs:

   INSERT INTO "Document"(
       "version",
       "changedate",
       "isdeleted",
       "id",

   ) VALUES (
       129,
       '2014-02-11 16:16:49.775791-05',
       '0',
       '0771bc29-ac5e-49a1-b5d7-3e4f7dccd03a',

   );
2. Save the version for each table in the client. Request the tables with the client version, and the server return the records > version, then merge them with the local DB.
3. Changes are done in the client. Send the record(s) to the server along with the last version recorded for each row from the server. Update the records and return back the version for each of them.

However, sometimes in the server I get more rows than in the client, or when two different devices are exchanging data at the end of the process the data is not identical. The process is in the background with no user intervention.

Comment: Where's the actual _question_ here?

Comment: If exist a algorithm that describe how sync 2 databases

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're sometimes getting too many rows because of this line in server.py

```
sql = table.select().where(table.c.version >= version)
```

If a table was updated between the time that you retrieved the version number and the time that this query finishes executing then you may get two or more versions of the table - you can try filtering out the duplicates after the query completes, or you can sort the data by version number in increasing order so that you iterate through the later versions after the earlier versions - you'll sync some tables more than once, but you'll sync the latest version after any the earlier versions so this shouldn't be a problem.

The problem of the data not being identical may just be a result of your sync not being atomic - the sources are being updated during the sync and so they may have newer data than the destination when the sync is complete.  This may also be a side-effect of the earlier problem of returning multiple versions of a table in line 31 of server.py - you might be overwriting later versions of a table with earlier versions, which you can prevent by filtering or sorting the query results.

Log the data (or just the table id and version) that's being synced from the sources and if you have multiple versions of a table then filter out all but the latest version - then after the sync if this data doesn't match the data in the destination then you'll know that something went wrong.

Comment: Well, I could debug by brote force, but the question is about if exist a well defined algorithm for this.